# Add text to plot legend without referring to line in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with two lines, where the legend entries are very similar except for some words (see below).

My code looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(36)
Data <- data.frame(
  date = sample((as.Date(as.Date("2011-12-30"):as.Date("2012-01-04"),
                         origin="1970-01-01")), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  group = sample(c("0", "1"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  outcome = sample(c("0", "1"), 1000, replace = TRUE))
Data %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date), group = factor(group)) %>%
  group_by(group, date) %>% #group
  summarise(prop = sum(outcome == "1")/n()) %>% #calculate proportion 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group))+
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "blue", "1" = "black"), labels = c("0" = 'Some text that repeats, the only unique thing being "A"', "1" = 'Some text that repeats, the only unique thing being "B"'), name = "Legend")
```

It produces the following graph:
[image: Sample plot]

I would like to simplify the legend. It should contain the following lines:

1. the title (`Legend`),
2. a text without any colored line (`Some text that repeats, the only unique thing being`) and then the entries with
3. the blue line with the text `A` and
4. the black line with the text `B`.

I.e. the desired output looks something like this:
[image: Desired output]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please add a desired output image. Show us your ms_paint skills.

Comment: It's Paint.NET, I insist ;) See updated question.

Comment: `scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "blue", "1" = "black"), 
                     labels = c("0" = 'A', 
                                "1" = 'B'), 
                     name = "Some text that repeats")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal:

```
scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "blue", "1" = "black"), 
                   labels = c("0" = '"A"', "1" = '"B"'), 
                   name = "Legend\nSome text that repeats,\nthe only unique thing being")
```

but I would remove `"Legend"` (not very informative IMHO).

[image]

To make a clear distinction between `"Legend"` and the subtitle text, you can bold it using `expression` and `atop`:

```
legend_title = expression(atop(bold("Legend\n"),
                         "Some text that repeats,\nthe only unique thing being"))

Data %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date), group = factor(group)) %>%
  group_by(group, date) %>% #group
  summarise(prop = sum(outcome == "1")/n()) %>% #calculate proportion 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group))+
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "blue", "1" = "black"), 
                     labels = c("0" = '"A"', "1" = '"B"'), 
                     name = legend_title)
```

[image]

You can then add spaces after `"Legend"` to align it to the left:

```
legend_title = expression(atop(bold("Legend                             \n"),
                         "Some text that repeats,\nthe only unique thing being"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that's only slightly hacky: add a dummy level to your `group` variable using `fct_expand` from `forcats` (included in the tidyverse), then use `fct_relevel` to make it the first level in the factor. That way, you have a fake observation that will be listed at the top of the legend, but doesn't actually have any data that comes with it.

The only things I changed besides adding that line were `drop = F` in the color scale, so even though there's no data associated with the dummy level, it will still show in the legend, and then the legend labels.

One drawback is that the legend key for the dummy variable is visible; there might be some ways to get rid of that, or you could just make it less visible by giving the legend keys a white background.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(36)
Data <- data.frame(
    date = sample((as.Date(as.Date("2011-12-30"):as.Date("2012-01-04"),
                                                 origin="1970-01-01")), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    group = sample(c("0", "1"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    outcome = sample(c("0", "1"), 1000, replace = TRUE))
Data %>%
    mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date), group = factor(group)) %>%
# add a dummy factor level & make it the first level
    mutate(group = group %>% fct_expand("dummy") %>% fct_relevel("dummy")) %>%
    group_by(group, date) %>% #group
    summarise(prop = sum(outcome == "1")/n()) %>% #calculate proportion 
    ggplot()+
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group))+
    geom_point(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "blue", "1" = "black", "dummy" = "transparent"), labels = c("0" = "A", "1" = "B", "dummy" = "Some text that repeats,\nthe only unique thing being"), name = "Legend", drop = F)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).